# Heuristics on Quantum computers

Tags: quantum-algorithms, quantum-advantage

I found the article :

[Strengths and Weaknesses of Quantum Computing, 1997
Charles H. Bennett, Ethan Bernstein, Gilles Brassard, Umesh Vazirani](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/9701001.pdf)

As far as I understand, this one states that quantum algorithms require exponential time to solve NP-complete problems in the black box model (i.e. ignores the detailed problem structure).

I used to use heuristics like genetic algorithms for which the problem is a black box encoded in several objective functions.

Does this article mean that, even if genetic algorithms could be implemented on a quantum computer,
there would be no exponential speedup (unlike the Shor's algorithm) ? and that in general it is not worth implementing heuristics on QCs because there is no quantum advantage to expect for, compared to classical computers ?

Comment: Both conclusions don't strictly follow from the BBBV theorem.  There are plenty of reasons to consider heuristics like QAOA or even a quantum version of a genetic algorithm which may indeed provide an exponential advantage *for certain problems* that may have precisely the kinds of structure that's taken advantage of by the heuristic.  The BBBV theorem says that we can't split P from BQP relative to an oracle, but that doesn't mean that quantum heuristics aren't worth exploring.  What would be improper to claim, though, is that quantum heuristics solve NP-complete problems in polynomial time.

Comment: I agree that quantum heuristics, like QAOA, are definitely worth, I was not meaning anything else. If I understand well your comment, in general a quantum genetic algorithm does not guarantee to provide an exponential speedup, except for some specific problems that take advantage of the genetic algorithm itself. Is it correct ?

Comment: Also, could you explain a little more what means "he BBBV theorem says that we can't split P from BQP relative to an oracle" ?

Comment: Actually I probably said that unartfully. I guess I just meant that the BBBV theorem implies that BQP is not so easily split from P as Grover’s algorithm is optimal in the black box/query model. So any exponential speedup from quantum computers has to find some way to take advantage of some *structure* inherent in the problem. *Perhaps* some quantum heuristics could tease out some structure for some problems for an exponential speedup, but that’s far from clear.

Comment: There are a lot of *classical* heuristics that appear to give very powerful speedups over and above random guessing. Often these classical heuristics can take advantage of some structure in the problem being attacked.

Comment: But the problems that classical heuristics appear to give an exponential speedup upon, such as Graph Isomorphism, are not likely to be NP-complete. So it’s justified in saying that classical heuristics don’t provide any evidence that P=NP.